# Expressjs: How to share route middleware accross routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have defined multiple route middleware and want to share them across multiple routes/controllers.

Here is my setup:

app.js requires ./routes/index.js:

```
// load fs module
var fs = require('fs');

// import routing files
module.exports = function(app){
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(function(file) {
        if (file == "index.js") return;
        var name = file.substr(0, file.indexOf('.'));
        require('./' + name)(app);
    });
};
```

index.js loads all routes automaticly in the dir. A possible routes file can look like:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/contacts', function(req, res, next) {
       // routing stuff
    });

};
```

Now I got route middleware:

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.authenticated) return next(new Error('user not authenticated'));
};

function loadUser(req, res, next) {
    var query = User.findById(req.session.user_id);
    query.populate('contacts');
    query.exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });
}
```

which I want to use like:

```
var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/contacts', isAuthenticated, loadUser, function(req, res, next) {
       res.json(req.user.contacts);
    });

};
```

I also would like to avoid requiring them accross all routing files.

A possible solution would also be:

```
// load fs module
var fs = require('fs');

var routeMiddleware = {
    loadUser: function(req, res, next) { // logic },
    isAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) { // logic },
};


// import routing files
module.exports = function(app){
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(function(file) {
        if (file == "index.js") return;
        var name = file.substr(0, file.indexOf('.'));
        require('./' + name)(app, routeMiddleware);
    });
};
```

but I think not the best...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally I would declare shared middleware in the app, not in the controllers, i.e.:

routes/home.js:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) { \\ Code }
```

app.js:

```
app.get('/', thisMiddleware, thatMiddleware, require('./routes/home'))
```

You can also make a stack (array, not an object):

```
theseMiddlewares = [thisMiddleware, thatMiddleware]
app.get('/', theseMiddlewares, require('./routes/home'))
```

And if these middlewares are used on all routes except a few, you can do the following:

```
theseMiddlewares = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url.match(some_regex_for_urls_to_skip)) next()
  else {
    \\ do stuff...
    next()
  }
}
```

Now you can `app.use(theseMiddlewares)` that middleware, or if it needs to happen in a certain order relative to other middleware, you can use `app.all('*', theseMiddlewares)`

Comment: Hello, interessting solutions. Is there also a way to save the middleware itself in app? I want to use them manuelly without having the stress of requiring them.

Comment: like i said, i would declare the routes and middlewares in the app, and make each module in the routes a middleware, not a route like you do. this way you only have to require the middlewares in your app, not each route module.